# Data from Firestore could not be converted back to C# objects

Tags: c#, google-cloud-firestore

I have this data model in Firestore where users can have multiple devices.

[image]

And I'm trying to convert it back to C# object using the below code:

```
DocumentReference docRef = db.Document("users/XKJxMfQ1rmmf873vzGof");
DocumentSnapshot snapshot = await docRef.GetSnapshotAsync();

if (snapshot.Exists)
{
    Model.User user = snapshot.ConvertTo<Model.User>();
}
```

As you can see below, the details such as the "Email" and "Name" (First & Last) were successfully converted back to the "User" object except for the "Devices" property which remained null:

[image]

Here's how my classes look like:

**User** class:

```
namespace GoogleCloudFirestoreDemo.Model
{
    [FirestoreData]
    public class User
    {
        
        [FirestoreProperty]
        public Name Name { get; set; }

        [FirestoreProperty]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [FirestoreProperty]
        public Dictionary<string, object> Devices { get; set; }

        /***
         * I also tried this kind of property but it never worked.
         * 
        [FirestoreProperty]
        public List<Device> Devices { get; set; }
        */
    }
}
```

**Device** class:

```
namespace GoogleCloudFirestoreDemo.Model
{
    [FirestoreData]
    public class Device
    {
        [FirestoreProperty]
        public string DeviceId { get; set; }

        [FirestoreProperty]
        public string Type { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Name** class:

```
namespace GoogleCloudFirestoreDemo.Model
{
    [FirestoreData]
    public class Name
    {
        [FirestoreProperty]
        public string First { get; set; }

        [FirestoreProperty]
        public string Last { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"{First} {Last}";
        }
    }
}
```

As much as possible, I want to retain how the data is structured in Firestore.
There must be something wrong with my C# code, and I was hoping you could assist me in resolving the issue.

Comment: This does *look* like it should work, although it's a while since I last dug into the serialization/deserialization code. Please could you file an issue on https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-dotnet (including the same code)? I'll self-assign as soon as I see it, then try to reproduce tomorrow morning UK time.

Comment: Ooh, I think I misread before - I was focusing on the Name part. I now see it's the Devices part which is causing the problem. Still definitely worth an issue, and I'll still look tomorrow :)

Comment: hi @JonSkeet, can I include this Stackoverflow link in the issue, as reference?

Comment: Yes, absolutely :) And if it turns out that it's not a bug in the library but just something non-obvious in terms of what you need to do, I'll add an answer here.

Comment: Thank you. I think it's more of an issue in my code. Here's the link to the issue (hope I logged it right): https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-dotnet/issues/10342

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GetDocumentSnapshot` returns the snapshot for a single document - it *doesn't* include any documents in subcollections of the document.

The screenshot you've provided shows 3 different documents:

- /users/XKJxMfQ1rmmf873vzGof
- /users/XKJxMfQ1rmmf873vzGof/Devices/DiaQ56wFcp6XET5N6yXM
- /users/XKJxMfQ1rmmf873vzGof/Devices/mh7P3LDIeWqs4alCbsSw

If you want to represent those all in a single C# object, you'd need to load the three snapshots separately and deserialize them to C# objects, then do whatever merging you need.

For example, here's code that I've tested, to load a single user and all their devices. The only change I made to your original `User` type was to the `Devices` property:

```cs
// Note: no FirestoreProperty here, as this isn't populated by the
// Firestore SDK as part of deserializing the document.
public Dictionary<string, Device> Devices { get; } = new();
```

Then the loading code:

```cs
async Task<User> LoadUser(FirestoreDb db, string userId)
{
    var usersRef = db.Collection("users");
    var userDocRef = usersRef.Document(userId);
    var userDocSnapshot = await userDocRef.GetSnapshotAsync();
    var user = userDocSnapshot.ConvertTo<User>();
    var devicesRef = userDocRef.Collection("Devices");
    var devicesSnapshot = await devicesRef.GetSnapshotAsync();
    foreach (var deviceSnapshot in devicesSnapshot.Documents)
    {
        user.Devices[deviceSnapshot.Id] = deviceSnapshot.ConvertTo<Device>();
    }
    return user;
}
```

You'd need to do something equivalent when saving a user, of course.

An alternative would be to use a nested map field within the user document. That has different tradeoffs in terms of ease of modification etc.